# Please help me create sql statement for my tables?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables(1.Employee 2.Family).
I want write a sql statement that produce the following output.

Pictures

```
Url : http://www.enterupload.com/8ryuew2anq0q/QUESTION1.jpg.html

Mirror 1 : http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?c9bea5b6b6.png

Mirror 2 : http://0k.010.img98.com/out.php/i342669_QUESTION1.png
```

[image: link text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets your desired results. Not sure why you would desire them though! (particularly the completely made up id values 9 and 10)

```
;WITH Employee AS
(
select 1 as ID, 'Alex' AS Name UNION ALL
select 2 as ID, 'James' AS Name UNION ALL
select 3 as ID, 'John' AS Name UNION ALL
select 4 as ID, 'Anthony' AS Name UNION ALL
select 5 as ID, 'Jack' AS Name
),
Family AS
(
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Kayla' AS Name, 'wife' AS Relative, 1 AS EmployeeID UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Benjamin', 'Son',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Alyssa', 'wife',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Emma', 'daughter',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Emily', 'daughter',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Elizabeth', 'wife',5 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Jackson', 'Son',5 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Laura', 'daughter',5 
),
cte AS
(

SELECT f.ID, f.Name, f.Relative, e.ID EmployeeID,
MAX(f.ID) OVER() + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.ID ORDER BY e.ID) AS RN
FROM Employee e LEFT OUTER JOIN Family f
ON e.ID = f.EmployeeId
)
SELECT COALESCE(ID,RN) AS ID, Name, Relative, EmployeeID 
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like just a left join to me.

```
SELECT Family.Name, Family.Relative, Employee.Id
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Family ON Employee.ID = Family.EmployeeID
```

If you really want that first column that says id and is new unique number then try this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(Family.ID,9999999)  ASC, Employee.ID ASC) AS ID, Family.Name, Family.Relative, Employee.Id as EmployeeID
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Family ON Employee.ID = Family.EmployeeID
```

Comment: @M R Jafari : if your question is answered please select the check box to the left.